When testing on mainnet fork with hardhat 2.22.2: Error: The response reported error `429`
when forking mainnet on hardhat version 2.22.2 I sometimes see this error:
It goes away after i try sending it again:
[Error: The response reported error `429`: `Your app has exceeded its compute units per second capacity. If you have retries enabled, you can safely ignore this message. If not, check out https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/throughput`. (optional data: None). Request: [{"id":8,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x90f79bf6eb2c4f870365e785982e1f101e93b906","0x12bb9c5"]},{"id":9,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionCount","params":["0x90f79bf6eb2c4f870365e785982e1f101e93b906","0x12bb9c5"]},{"id":10,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getCode","params":["0x90f79bf6eb2c4f870365e785982e1f101e93b906","0x12bb9c5"]}]] {
  code: 'GenericFailure'
}


Seems to be a bug that was recently introduced to hardhat.
downgrading to "hardhat": "2.21"
seemed to fix it
